# Highcharts - show blank X Axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, axis

Is it possible to have, for example, column chart without X axis. I just want it to be blank line. I tried this code, but still gives me default numbers:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: [],
        showEmpty: true // Think this is for something else.
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        type: 'column',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]

    }]
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/asr3z1p8/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to disable the labels:

```
 xAxis: {
     labels: {
         enabled: false
     }
 }
```